# Code Signing Issues When Binding a Swift Library in a Xamarin App

Tags: swift, xamarin, xamarin.ios, azure-devops

We have bound a Swift library to use in our Xamarin app but we are having code signing issues when we try and submit the build to Apple, an example would be:

`Payload/MyApp.Touch.app/: a sealed resource is missing or invalid file modified: /Users/Me/Downloads/Payload/MyApp.Touch.app/Frameworks/libswiftSceneKit.dylib file modified`

This error is repeated for every `.dylib`.

This is only happening when we attempt to build and deploy via AzureDevOps, I've verified using `codesign` that a local build doesn't display this problem.

There is more detail on problem here: https://github.com/Flash3001/Xamarin.SwiftSupport/issues/26, but has anyone else experienced this kind of code signing issue for builds being deployed from AzureDevOps?

Comment: just check what is the code signing of your .dylib under framework it should be same as your main app. if it is different then you need to resign.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gotten to the bottom of why the code signature is being invalidated but as a workaround I've added a step to use `codesign` to re-sign the bundle after the initial build.